# Array with flags

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let say I have an array of bool flags, it would be set to true or false depends on the condition.

Let say the index 1 ,2 ,6 have been set and all other flags are not set, I need to call `functionA`, and if index 2,3, 5 have been set and all other flags are not set, I need to call `functionB`. Is there an easy way where I could perform the logic above other than doing this:

```
if(array[1] == true && array[2] == true && array[6] == true && 
   array[3] == false && array[4] == false && array[5] == false)
{
  functionA();
}
```

Comment: You may skip the `== true` part, and replace the `== false` part with the `!` operator.

Comment: Does this array have a fixed size?

Comment: @n.m. “you may” should really be “you absolutely should”.

Comment: I would suggest to aim for more easily readable & understandable code rather than fancy, nerdy stuff. The best source codes are not the ones which are compact but the ones which are easily readable & understandable.

Answer (score 8):

### Maintenance and readability nightmare!

Consider this instead:

```
bool temperature_sensor_tripped(const bool_array& flags)
{
     return flags[1];
}

// [...]

if (temperature_sensor_tripped(array) 
    && moisture_sensor_tripped(array)
    && !alarm_dispatched(array))
{
    functionA();
}
```

This has the advantage that `moisture_sensor_tripped()` and its kin can be called from other functions without you (or the maintainer) remembering the order of the flags.

Comment: This, and I would also name the indices, e.g. `const int temperature_sensor_idx = 1;` and then `return flags[temperature_sensor_idx]`.

Comment: @UncleZeiv: can be nicer to use an enum for that... either way, doing that gets all the benefits of the wrapper functions Johnsyweb's suggests (and more) without as much verbosity.

Comment: @Tony: true, enum is the way to go; anyway I was suggesting that *in addition* to Johnsyweb's solution, not as an alternative!

Comment: @UncleZeiv: yes, I thought you were - which is why I tried to point out that is it actually a valid alternative....

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion:

```
bool truecondition = array[1] && array[2] && array[6];
bool falsecondition = !array[3] && !array[4] && !array[5];

if (truecondition && falsecondition)
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: +1 One crucial aspect of source code is it should be readable & understandable easily not for you but the person who will work on it after you. Your solution fits the criteria best of all other solutions.

Comment: Could be `bool falsecondition = !truecondition`. :P

Comment: +1, but I would avoid negative words (like `false`) in identifiers, "`if (!notDisabled())`" makes my brain ache.

Answer (score 3):

You can skip the unnecessary `== true` comparisons and use `!` for the `false` cases:

```
if (array[1] && array[2] && array[6] && !array[3] && !array[4] && !array[5])
```

Alternatively, make a bool array and compare against that:

```
bool condition[6] = { true, true, false, false, false, true };
if (std::equal(array+1, array+7, condition)) { // +1 for your 1-based indexes
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `bool`, you can use `char` instead, and treat each bit as one flag. Say this **char** flags (which is actually a combination of many flags) is this:

```
char flags;
```

So if index `1,2,6` are set, that means

```
//index count starts from rightmost bit
flags = 0100 0110 (binary) =  64 + 4 + 2 = 70 (decimal)
```

Similarly, index `2,3,5` set means

```
flags = 0010 1100 (binary) =  32 + 8 + 4 = 44 (decimal)
```

So you can write

```
if (flags == 70 ) //i.e when index 1,2,6 are set
{
     functionA();
}
else if ( flags == 44 ) //i.e when index 2,3,5 are set
{
    functionB();
}
```

As size of `char` is one byte, so you can have at most `8` flags in one variable (assuming `CHAR_BIT` is `8` on your machine which is most likely to be true). But you need more flags, then you can take `int` instead, and work accordingly.

---

Well, that is the basic idea. Now you can improve that as follows:

```
enum flag
{
     flag0 = 1 << 0, //1   = 0000 0001
     flag1 = 1 << 1, //2   = 0000 0010
     flag2 = 1 << 2, //4   = 0000 0100
     flag3 = 1 << 3, //8   = 0000 1000
     flag4 = 1 << 4, //16  = 0001 0000
     flag5 = 1 << 5, //32  = 0010 0000
     flag6 = 1 << 6, //64  = 0100 0000
     flag7 = 1 << 7, //128 = 1000 0000
};

char flags = 0 ;

//this is how you can set flags!
flags |= flag1 ;         //set index 1        (one at a time)
flags |= flag2 | flag6 ; //set index 2 and 6  (more than one at a time)

if ( flags == (flag1 | flag2 | flag6) )
{
      functionA();
} 
else if ( flags == (flag2 | flag3 | flag5) )
{
      functionB();
} 

//and this is how you can unset flags!
flags &= ~flag1 ;          //unset index 1        (one at a time)
flags &= ~flag2 & ~flag6 ; //unset index 2 and 6  (more than one at a time)
```

See this online demo : http://www.ideone.com/6BdGf

Answer (score 2):

You could go with `std::bitset` if the array has a fixed size and test with simple masks:

```
#include <bitset>

void funcA(){
}

void funcB(){
}

enum FuncMasks{
  funcA_Mask = 0x23, // 0010 0011
  funcB_Mask = 0x16, // 0001 0110
};

int main(){
  std::bitset<6> flags;

  if(flags.to_ulong() & funcA_Mask)
    funcA();
  else if(flags.to_ulong() & funcB_Mask)
    funcB();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easier way would be using an integer for all those flags and then using bit operations. You could as well use `std::bitset` in case you're looking for a ready to be used solution.

```
enum flags { // i use hexadecimal notation as it's easier to see unused flags - using 8 bits/1 byte is enough for you but you could extend it even more as well
    FLAG_NONE  = 0x00;
    FLAG_ONE   = 0x01;
    FLAG_TWO   = 0x02;
    FLAG_THREE = 0x04;
    // ...
};

// To set some flags you use bitwise operators:
char flags_set = FLAG_ONE | FLAG_THREE | FLAG_SIX;
flags_set |= FLAG_FOUR; // add fourth flag
flags_set &= ~FLAG_TWO; // remove second flag (if set)

// Similar way you can check the flags and you've got "talking" code that's a lot easier to understand than tons of if()s
if (flags_set & (FLAG_ONE | FLAG_TWO | FLAG_SIX))
    functionA();
elseif (flags_set & (FLAG_TWO | FLAG_THREE | FLAG_FIVE))
    functionB();
```

Comment: `&` your flags will clear them all. You probably meant to use `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using `valarray`:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <iostream>

bool all(const std::valarray<bool> & va) {
  return va.min();
}

bool none(const std::valarray<bool> & va) {
  return !va.max();
}

int main() {
  bool bits_init[] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
  std::valarray<bool> bits(bits_init, 7);
  size_t true_bits_init[] = {1, 2, 6};
  std::valarray<size_t> true_bits(true_bits_init, 3);
  size_t false_bits_init[] = {0, 3, 4, 5};
  std::valarray<size_t> false_bits(false_bits_init, 4);

  if(all(bits[true_bits]) && none(bits[false_bits]))
    std::cout << "functionA" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "functionB" << std::endl;
  bits[2] = false;
  if(all(bits[true_bits]) && none(bits[false_bits]))
    std::cout << "functionA" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "functionB" << std::endl;
  bits[2] = true;
  bits[3] = true;
  if(all(bits[true_bits]) && none(bits[false_bits]))
    std::cout << "functionA" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "functionB" << std::endl;
}
```

I don't know if it is what you need. It does provide a lot of flexibility if the size of your arrays varies.

Answer (score 0):

If the functions have a return type that can be evaluated in a boolean context (e.g. bool, int, double, pointer), you can write:

```
Array& a = array; // for brevity...
a[1] && a[2] && a[6] && functionA() ||
a[2] && a[3] && a[5] && functionB() ||
...
```

You may or may not prefer this `&&` chaining of functions to the explicit "if" usage (the style above's popular with some perl hackers, FWIW).  The other aspects the reference, which is a good idea for really repetitive code.

If the functions lack such a return type, you can use a wrapper with a return type to call them.

Alternatively, rather than having a plain array you can make it an object with `operator[]` providing indexed access, then add functionality to it allowing:

```
array.run_if(1, 2, 6, functionA)
     .run_if(2, 3, 5, functionB);
```

Here, the main issue is how to handle different numbers of indices.  Options include:

- overload for 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. indices, assuming the upper limit's manageable
- use a preprocessor facility to automatically generate a large but finite set of overloads (see Loki or boost for examples)
- put the function first, then use `...` and `stdargs`, with a sentinel value such as -1 (no arbitrary limit, but more error prone)
- accept indices in a `std::vector<>`, array (which a template can bind to, discovering the number of elements, though C++ lacks an "array literal" so you need a named variable to pass rather than `run_if([1, 2, 6], functionA)`.

As illustrated, the chaining of `run_if` calls suggests `run_if` return a reference to `*this`, but this implies continued matching and potential function calls after the first match.  Some object state would need to track and prevent this.