# Big if else statement

Tags: c++, algorithm

If have a big ( about 100 plus) if else statement like below and the if else condition might be irregular(for example some depends on 3 variables, some on 4), is there any way of making it simpler?

Basically I have a table of around 100 plus rows, with the a,b,c and d as the column. Based on a,b,c and d, I need to perform 3 different type of function.

The table describes a set a business rules.

```
 uint8 a;
 uint8 b;
 uint16 c;
 uint8  d;

 if      ( a == 1 &&   b == 1           && c == 0)           { functionA();}
 else if ( a == 5 &&   b == 5           && c == 2 && d == 2) { functionB();}
 else if ( a == 1 && (b ==36 || b == 7) && c == 0)           { functionC();}  
 else if ( a == 3 &&   b == 3                     && d == 50) {functionA();}
    :
    :
```

Comment: Why in the world did you get a `if...else` statement like that?

Comment: It would be nice if you explained what you were trying to accomplish

Comment: I have a table with column of a, b , c and d. Based on the value of the column, it needs to updates some variables.

Comment: There's usually a pattern somewhere, you probably need to redo your functions, but it's hard to say without more information.

Comment: If you're expressing something like business rules, I don't know how you make it any cleaner than this.

Comment: @muntoo: your edit deemphasises the fact that each variable isn't tested in each `if`... I think it *should* be rolled back personally, though not strongly enough to do so myself...

Comment: @muntoo: Your edit changes the meaning of the question.  *Do not!*  Post an answer instead.

Comment: There are some excellent suggestions in answer to [one of your earlier questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6263222/78845). I dread to think what your next question is going to be...

Comment: @leslieg: what is the range of the values for a, b, c and d ?

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of ways to make it simpler, for example:

- you can populate a map from a struct holding `a`, `b`, `c`,  and `d` values to check for to the function to call (the code to populate the map may still be a mess, but it'll be faster and cleaner executing; can add two keys for cases ala `b == x || b == y`)
- you can manually factor the conditions: given your example, `if (a == 1) if (b == 1 && c == 0) functionA(); else if ((b == 36 || b == 7) && c == 0) functionC();`.  `switch` statements may make this cleaner.  In such a factoring, you can also use `<`, `<=`, `>`, and/or `>=` to divide larger search spaces, improving performance to from O(N) to O(log2N).
- for the common simple case of testing `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` once, use a macro ala `#define ELIF_ABCD(A, B, C, D, F) else if (a == (A) && b == (B) && c == (C) && d == (D)) F();`.  Add macros as necessary for other combinations of tests e.g. `ABD`, `ABC`, `AD`.
- (may make the code more cryptic), but could explore bit-shifting and ORing together the values into a large enough type (`int64_t`) then e.g. binary search an array of function pointers

Something to look out for though is that the if/else chain may contain things like:

```
if (a == 1 && c == 3 && d == 2) functionY();
else if (a == 1 && b == 2 && c == 3) function X();
```

Here, the order is significant as an input can match both.  This aspect can easily get lost or altered if the searches are factored differently or some manner of indexing to function pointer is used, which is one argument in favour of the macro approach above.

Comment: Make the macro with just `if` and you can use it in all the ifs: `IF(1,2,3,5,foo) else IF(1,2,3,4,bar)`

Comment: @Martinho: lots of choices - another appealing one is simply `#define ABCDF(...) if (...) { F(); return; }`... get rid of the `if`/`else` chain completely.

Answer (score 2):

Following from Tony's suggestion to use a map you could probably optimize it a bit.

You could encode all 4 of the numbers as a single uint64_t (or smaller depending on the range of their values).

```
uint64_t h = (a << 32) + (b << 24) + (c << 8) + d;
```

You could then build a `std::map<uint_64_t, void (*)()>` that maps the hash to a function pointer.  It may take some effort to construct the map though.  I think it would be better for you to listen to everyone the other suggestions and refactor your code.

Comment: This is similar to my 4th suggestion, though I recommend there that the hash be used to search an array/vector.  Thinking about it more, there's the problem of handling cases when one or more of the variables isn't being tested - may need to have a mask value for each search hash, and bitwise-AND the mask with the hash of a, b, c, d before comparing the result with the search hash.

Comment: @Tony: Ah we may have posted at the same time, I guessed map since I assume there will be a huge number of unused hits.  A vector would be way too big I think.

Comment: @GWW: the `vector` can be packed and binary searched, so will consume less memory than a `map` (depends on implementation, but I'd say 1/2 to 1/10th), and be slightly faster to lookup.  (Sparse arrays are most wasteful of virtual memory, but with a 40-bit key I also feel uncomfortable with their use here).

Comment: @Tony: Ah I see what you mean.  That's clever

Comment: This doesn't work for the reason @Tony stated in his comment. (See my answer below).

Comment: @Tony, BTW, you don't want to AND the mask with the hash, you want to XOR it. ANDing will only zero bits in the hash, and not set any, which causes the hash to become unbalanced, and skews it toward the lower end of the table.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod.  To illustrate, say we're checking for `a == 2`, `b == 3`, and `d == 5` but don't care about `c`, though the input is 7.  We bitshift-OR/hash the input to "2375", then AND that with "1101" (so to speak) to get "2305", so we search for `("1101", "2305")` in the vector or map.  Note that there might also be a `("1111", "2305")` in the container, representing the requirement that `c == 0`... no problem as it doesn't match. The exact key values don't matter as long as they can be ordered to allow quick searching + they're unique.

Comment: (Note that GWW decided to call his bitwise-combination of a, b, c, and d a hash - and I've run with that - but the container we're storing in is sorted - e.g. `std::map` or sorted `std::vector` - *not* a hash map, so there's no issue of "skew"/grouping/clustering/collisions/whatever).

Comment: @Tony, we're on the same page (see my answer). I thought you were talking about serializing the a, b, c, d values, then hashing, then ANDing the mask, then using the result as a key in a hash map.

Answer (score 1):

Split it up based on your 4 variables

```
if(a==1)
{
    if(b==1)
    {

    }
    else if(b==3)
    {

    }
}
else if(a==3)
{

}
```

that would make it a little simpler to read and follow

Comment: `switch...case` is more idiomatic.  For a limited-range type like uint8_t, the compiler might even make it a jump table...

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider something like this - which keeps the conditions with the functions and makes the whole lot much easier to test and extend (In my opinion).

You can probably produce subclasses that take constructor parameters to reduce the total number of classes required.

```
class ICase
{
  virtual ~ICase() {}
  virtual bool matches_arguments( int a, int b, int c ) const =0;
  virtual void do_it( int a, int b, int c)=0;
};

class CaseA : public ICase
{
  bool matches_arguments( int a, int b, int c ) const { return ( a == 1 &&   b == 1           && c == 0); }
  bool do_it(int a, int b, int c) { functionA(); }
};

...
//Some setup - only need to do this once
std::vector< shared_ptr<ICase> > cases;
cases.push_back( new CaseA );
cases.push_back( new CaseB );

//The conditionals
for( int i=0; i<cases.size(); ++i)
{
  if( cases[i]->matches_arguments(a,b,c) ) { cases[i]->do_it(a,b,c); break; }
}
```

Comment: Oh and of course you should use descriptive and sensible names for your classes - that will help understandability a heap.

Comment: This will make the if-else chain simple but... won't it move the nightmare into the Case classes?

Comment: Possibly. However,  often its i) easier to refactor to exploit similarities between cases ii) Easier to test each case, iii) Easier to add new cases, iv) Easier to understand what each case is doing if well named. - How many (if any) of these apply to the original post will depend a lot on what structure is really underlying the `if` mess.

Comment: And you have now increased the amount of code by an order of magnitude, at least. Hooray for the Java way of programming

Answer (score 1):

To expand Tony's first point:

> you can populate a map from a struct holding a, b, c, and d values to check for to the function to call

Wrap all of your variables up in a state object or something:

```
struct state {
    uint8 a;
    uint8 b;
    uint16 c;
    uint8 d;
}
```

And add a bunch of those possible states to lists:

```
std::set<state> functionASet;
functionASet.insert(aState);
...
```

Then test whether the set contains a state constructed of the current values for `a, b, c, d`:

```
// init a state struct with current values for a, b, c, d
if(functionASet.find(currentValues) != functionASet.end())
    functionA();
else if(functionBSet.find(currentValues) != functionASet.end())
    functionB();
else ...
```

OR, add the states to a map:

```
typedef void (*func)();

std::map<state, func> functionMap;
```

And simply call the function which matches the found state:

```
std::map<state, func>::iterator search = functionMap.find(currentValues);
if(search != functionMap.end())
    (search->second())();
```

Comment: Problem with this is that some of the columns are don't cares. E.g., the first conditional has d as a don't care. You would need to create 256 state objects (one for each possible d value) to cover the first conditional.

Answer (score 1):

To do this correctly and efficiently, you first need to standardize the representation of each row and transform it into compact data that can be indexed or sorted. You could try doing this by simply serializing the values of the columns into a fixed-length string, and then inserting this string and a pointer for the appropriate function into a map with the string as the key and the function pointer as the value.

However, the problem is a bit more complex because in some rows some columns do not count, they are "don't cares." Assuming there is no value in each column that can act as a "dont care" value, in addition to values for each column, the key also must contain data indicating which columns are significant. We can do this by appending an extra byte to the string that contains a bit mask indicating which columns are significant. For map searching to work correctly in this case, insignificant columns must always contain the same value in the key (zero is a good choice).

Now we have a only to write a function to construct a six-byte key from the columns of each row of our table. Use this function to do the initial map inserts and the lookups after the map is built.

This method is quite fast for lookups, O(log n), where n is number of rows.

Comment: the issues here are that 1) when searching for a, b, c, d, we don't know which of the values may be "don't cares", so we'd need to try all combinations of values an don't cares in order to find all possible relevant map entries 2) this doesn't preserve the ordering of multiple tests in the existing if/else code that could match the same input.  I'm still at a loss for how to handle this better though if darvids0n's simpler implementation that avoids don't care values in favour of populating all combinations proves too unwieldy in practice.

Comment: @Tony, I may be incorrect, but I was assuming that OP's if-else statements were a first attempt and that the ordering of the if-else statements in the example and in OP's data table were not significant. This also assumes that there are no conflicts in the data, i.e., that the a,b,c,d space is partitioned across functions A,B,C -- the criteria for functions A,B,C are mutually exclusive. If this is not the case, then the data can be preprocessed using boolean algebra reduction, so as to resolve conflicts based on some criteria, such as order in the original data table.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamt about this question overnight .. and have come up with a neat solution (inspired by the matching systems used in the google test ilbraries)

The core if mess becomes something like this - which I think is quite pretty.

```
  Params(1,2,3,4)
    .do_if( match(1,_,3,5), functionA )
    .do_if( match(1,_,3,4), functionB )
    .do_if( match( _, OR(2,3),3,5), functionC )
//    .do_if( match(1,_,4,6)|match(3,_,5,8) ), functionD )
    ;
```

Final line I haven't implemented yet. `_` means match any digit, `OR` means match either (though you can nest it `OR(1,OR(2,3))` should be fine.

The rest of the support code is a mess of template functions to make this work. If there's interest I can post a more thorough description of what's going on .. but its not overly complicated - just long. I expect it can be cleaned up   a bit too...

It can probably be pulled out and generalized into a nice library too - though I'd probably look at adapting the google test code instead of basing anything off this code ;)

```
struct RawParams
{
  RawParams( int a, int b, int c, int d) : a_(a), b_(b), c_(c), d_(d) {}
  int a_,b_,c_,d_;
};

struct ParamsContinue
{
  RawParams * p_;

  ParamsContinue() : p_(0) {}
  ParamsContinue( RawParams * p ) : p_(p) {}

  template<typename CONDITION, typename FN>
  ParamsContinue do_if( CONDITION cond, FN fn )
  {
    if( !p_ ) { return ParamsContinue(); }
    if( cond(p_->a_,p_->b_,p_->c_,p_->d_) ) { fn(); return ParamsContinue(); }
    return *this;
  }
};

struct Params
{
  Params( int a, int b, int c, int d) : params_(a,b,c,d) {}
  RawParams params_;

  template<typename CONDITION, typename FN>
  ParamsContinue do_if( CONDITION cond, FN fn )
  {
    return ParamsContinue(&params_).do_if(cond,fn);
  }
};

struct AnySingleMatcher
{
  bool operator()(int i) const { return true; }
};

AnySingleMatcher _;

template<typename M1, typename M2, typename M3, typename M4>
struct Match
{
  Match( M1 in_m1, M2 in_m2, M3 in_m3, M4 in_m4 ) : 
    m1(in_m1),
    m2(in_m2),
    m3(in_m3),
    m4(in_m4)
  {}

  bool operator()( int a, int b, int c, int d) const { return m1(a)&&m2(b)&&m3(c)&&m4(d); }

  M1 m1;
  M2 m2;
  M3 m3;
  M4 m4;
};

struct AnyMatcher {};
struct IntMatcher
{
  IntMatcher(int i) : i_(i) {}
  bool operator()(int v) const { return v==i_; }
  int i_;
};

template<typename T>
struct as_matcher
{
  typedef T type;
  static T as( T t ) { return t; }
};

template<>
struct as_matcher<int>
{
  typedef IntMatcher type;
  static IntMatcher as( int i ) { return IntMatcher( i ); }
};

template<typename M1, typename M2, typename M3, typename M4 >
Match< typename as_matcher<M1>::type, typename as_matcher<M2>::type, typename as_matcher<M3>::type, typename as_matcher<M4>::type >
match( M1 m1, M2 m2, M3 m3, M4 m4 )
{
  return 
    Match< typename as_matcher<M1>::type, typename as_matcher<M2>::type, typename as_matcher<M3>::type, typename as_matcher<M4>::type >(
      as_matcher<M1>::as(m1), as_matcher<M2>::as(m2), as_matcher<M3>::as(m3), as_matcher<M4>::as(m4) );
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct OrMatcher
{
  OrMatcher( T1 t1, T2 t2 ) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {}
  T1 t1_;
  T2 t2_;
  bool operator()(int i) const { return t1_(i) || t2_(i); }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
OrMatcher< typename as_matcher<T1>::type, typename as_matcher<T2>::type > OR( T1 t1, T2 t2 )
{
  return OrMatcher< typename as_matcher<T1>::type, typename as_matcher<T2>::type >( as_matcher<T1>::as(t1),as_matcher<T2>::as(t2) );
};

#include <iostream>
void functionA(){ std::cout<<"In A"<<std::endl;};
void functionB(){ std::cout<<"In B"<<std::endl;};
void functionC(){ std::cout<<"In C"<<std::endl;};
void functionD(){ std::cout<<"In D"<<std::endl;};

int main()
{
  Params(1,2,3,4)
    .do_if( match(1,_,3,5), functionA )
    .do_if( match(1,_,3,4), functionB )
    .do_if( match( _, OR(2,3),3,5), functionC )
//    .do_if( match(1,_,4,6)|match(3,_,5,8) ), functionD )
    ;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Without further details, one can only guesss as to how to simplify it.

One possibility is the use of boolean variables. If you are constantly evaluating certain combinations, you could save that reevaluation by using booleans.

If there are a fixed set of conditions, you could also use a bit mask against an `int` and then do a `case`.

But again, these are just guesses without knowing more details about what you are really doing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems really messy :/

When you need to describe business rules, you should use a *descriptive* approach rather than an imperative approach. It is much more readable and it is usually much easier to adapt the rules.

My first thought is to use a table, indexed by a, b, c and d, and have function pointers (or functors) within.

The initialization code will be a bit frightening, my advice would be to keep it ordered lexicographically:

```
// Note: you don't have to initialize the null values if the variable is static
Table[0][0][0][1] = functionA;
Table[0][3][0][1] = functionB;
...
```

Retrieving the function is then a piece of cake, just remember to test for nullity if it's possible that there is no function (and `assert` otherwise).

Another solution would be to break down the choice into steps, using functions:

- switch on `a`, choose the function to call (use the `default` to handle the case where you do not care about `a`)
- switch on `b`, `c`, `d` ....

Example:

```
void update(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  switch(a) {
  case 0: updateA0(b, c, d); break;
  case 1: updateA1(b, c, d); break;
  default: updateAU(b, c, d); break;
  }
}

void updateA0(int b, int c, int d) {
  switch(b) {
  case 0: updateA0B0(c, d); break;
  case 1: updateA0B1(c, d); break;
  default: updateA0BU(c, d); break;
  }
}

// etc...
```

It makes it easier to "follow" the update chain, and to apply local updates. Also, the logic being proper to each subfunctions, it's easy to apply ranges selections (`if (b >= 5 && b < 48)`) without "breaking" the pattern or duplicating the initialization. Finally, depending on the likeliness on some paths, you can easily choose to switch on `d` first in `updateA1` if it makes it easier.

It is at least as flexible as your current solution, but much more readable/maintainable.